# How can i get the ID from an Object after SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two Objects

- Post
- Image

I upload Images with my create_post Controller and want to create image objects after the creation of my posts. I want to add the PostId in my image objects but i dont know how i get the postID after the SaveChangesAsync().

This is my code:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost([FromForm]PostModel post)
    {
        var user = User.FindFirst("UserID")?.Value;
        if (post.content != null && user != null)
        {
            var postdata = new Posts
            {
                Content = post.content,
                CreatorId = user,
                Created = DateTime.Now
            };
            context.Posts.Add(postdata);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            if (post.Images != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in post.Images){
                    var image = new Images
                    {
                        userId = user,
                        postId = post.Id
                    };

                    var uniqueFileName = GetUniqueFileName(file.FileName);
                    var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Images/PostImages");
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, uniqueFileName);
                    await file.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                    image.imageFilePath = filePath;

                }
            }

            return Ok(post);

        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new { ErrorMessage = "Textfeld darf nicht leer sein!" });
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your `postData` object should have a `PostId` property that will be populated by EF once you've called `SaveChangesAsync`.

Comment: Ah perfect :) you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

From your code you don't appear to be persisting or doing anything with the image entity after creating it. When you set up the relationship /w navigation properties you can have EF automatically persist the relationships without needing to manually set the FK relationships.

I.e.

```
if (post.content == null || user == null)
    return BadRequest(new { ErrorMessage = "Textfeld darf nicht leer sein!" });

var uploadPath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Images/PostImages");
var postdata = new Posts
{
    Content = post.content,
    CreatorId = user,
    Created = DateTime.Now // could be managed by DB /w Default constraint.
};

var images = post.Images
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        File = x  // our file we will use to copy.
        ImageData = new Images // The image entity we'll add to the Post.
        {
            userId = user,
            imageFilePath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, GetUniqueFileName(x.FileName));
        }
    }).ToList();

foreach(var image in images)
{
    await image.File.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(image.ImageData.imageFilePath, FileMode.Create));
    postdata.Images.Add(image.ImageData);
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
post.PostId = postdata.PostId;

return Ok(post);
```

The point here would be to avoid calling `SaveChanges` more than once if you want to save both the post and the files. Rather than creating an Image and setting the PostID, which you won't have until after calling `SaveChanges`, you can leverage navigation properties, create the Image and add it to the Post.Images collection. When EF goes to save the Post and its related Images it will manage the necessary FK assignment automatically.

The reason to avoid multiple `SaveChanges` calls is to help ensure that related changes are either committed together or not at all. If you save Post, then later go to save Images and there is a problem saving the image, the Post has already been committed. This leaves incomplete data persisted in the DB which can interfere with attempts to correct and retry the operation.

Getting the Post ID after saving is still useful such as to pass the ID back to the view after the save is completed for any further update requests etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the Id before SaveChanges, by accessing the property "Entity" of the "EntityEntry" like this :

```
postdata = context.Posts.Add(postdata).Entity;
```

After this, postdata will have Id value without SaveChanges.